# php 7.0 fatal error Call to undefined method Product::

Tags: php

I try to used to an old customized module in my Prestashop that runs with php 7.0.
I got an error and no idea...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Product::getFrontFeaturesHiddenByNameStatic()
```

And here is the line of code.

```
$feature = Product::getFrontFeaturesHiddenByNameStatic((int)($params['cookie']->id_lang), $product['id_product'],'_Descriptif accueil');
```

And that function is defined in "override" folder.

```
public static function getFrontFeaturesHiddenByNameStatic($id_lang, $id_product, $featureName) {
    self::getFrontFeaturesStatic($id_lang, $id_product);
    if( isset(self::$_frontFeaturesCacheHidden[$id_product.'-'.$id_lang]) )
    foreach(self::$_frontFeaturesCacheHidden[$id_product.'-'.$id_lang] as $feature) {
        if( $featureName == $feature["name"] )
            return $feature;
    }
    return null; // nothing has been found
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: please show your code for clarity and better understanding.

Comment: Forgot the line of code that seems to be a problem...
//$feature = Product::getFrontFeaturesHiddenByNameStatic((int)($params['cookie']->id_lang), $product['id_product'],'_Descriptif accueil');

Comment: @Pat Can you add that code from your comment into your original post?

Comment: The error is self-explanatory, that method does not exist in the class `Product`. Was this module working before? Did you do any recent update?

Comment: Indeed, that method is not in Product class, but it should work as it was definided in override, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.
Actually the override definition was not in the right folder.
It was in override/classes and failed, while set in modules/mymodule/override/classes, it seems to work fine...
Thank for your help!